RDP to DB server to run the worker service exe and it gives error "Login failed for user "domain/xyz" which is rdp user not a user used in connection
Worker service able to connect and run without an issue in a development laptop with windows 11 enterprise. It is not working in Windows 2016 standard DB server where is is deployed voa Azure CI/CD and could not esatblish connection to database.
I do RDP to DB server to run the worker service exe and it gives message as Login failed for user "domain/xyz" which is rdp user not a sqlserver user used in connection string.
I see the worker service folder has runtime subfolder and it has .net core 8.03 but Worker service developed in .net core 8.0. Should I install .net core 8.0 runtime
Connection string used is "Server=xyz.a.b;Database=db1;User Id=user;Password=pwd;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Encrypt=Optional;
The SQL Server used is Microsoft SQL Server 2022 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 
I could connect to DB through SSMS in that server with same user used in the app.
The problem is why it is show RDP user which is not used to connect DB as login failed.
Please advise

If i recall correct Trusted_Connection means Windows Auth so it uses the WIndowsCredentials not what you deliver via UserID/Password Credentials. You do both in your connection string and that feels wrong. It should be either/or.  Credentials OR Trusted_Connection.

It works on setting Trusted_Connection=false; but could not understand why development system it is not giving issue. is it using username and pwd for development system. How is it ?
